# Where is my exception in my Web Profiler?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I have noticed running my appliation in prod mode reduces the exception page of the web profiler to "Oops! An Error Occurred".

[image]

My config.yml:

```
framework:
    profiler:
        lifetime:    604800
        only_exceptions: true
```

The related profiler file contains the exception and the prod.log file as well.

But why is the detailed exception missing there?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `Debug` component is not enabled by default in `prod` environment.
`Debug` component has own `ExceptionHandler` and `ErrorHandler` that will produce standard debug information for you.

Comment: So the best way would be to replace the Exception and ErrorHandler in Prod?

Comment: If you have an example how to achieve it I would appreciate.